# Can I upgrade the memory on late 2013 Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, memory

The below is my macOS version with basic capabilities :

[image]

While developing my apps, my Mac often shows great memory usage and swaps. These makes my Mac running and building apps slowly.

I would like to find out the ways to increase my SSD capacities and RAM . Would you please tell me how can I upgrade my RAM and SSD?

Comment: @Allan Taking cue from your flag, I have flagged this answer as well. I noticed your flag only after posting the answer. Really nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

The RAM is soldered on so it is not upgradeable.

The SSD CAN be upgraded, with a standard PCIe M.2 drive if you buy an internal adapter ($2-3 on ebay) since Apple added compatibility for the new M2 Drives with High Sierra. They are much cheaper and have faster read/write speeds than the originals. OR there are some standard SSDs like this one you can buy if you don’t want to use an adapter: https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-and-15-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2014-SSD/IF123-026-5

Just search for „MacBook Pro Late 2013 SSD“ on Google/eBay/Amazon and you will get some more results.

Comment: See OWC for SSD upgrades https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015

Comment: i would get an adaptor which is about £8 on amazon. then use another SSD NVme 500gb from crucial p2 (great brand) for about £40. much cheaper than OWC ones (which can fit directly but much more expensive)